# Error in flow type signature. Why?

Tags: flowtype

Here is the exemple:

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5swBDMACgAcyAnMgWwGcAuMAb2oEZ3n86hbAHMANGGoAmAPx8BQ4QF8AlOwBucQgBNOi9FjxESYAEZVVnHnMEjFnVGDB0Apvkx1SXXmADk-G8I+igDcqHqoavSmAErOzJgw+GAAvKaUyqGoZJQmsfGJGUA

```
/* @flow */

function a (params: {p1: string, p2?: string}): void {}

function b (): {p1: string} {
  return {p1: 'string'};
} 

var bResult = b();

a(bResult);
```

And I got an flow error

```
3: function a (params: {p1: string, p2?: string}): void {}
                       ^ property `p2`. Property not found in
11: a(bResult);
      ^ object type
```

Why this error happens? 
Why signature `{p1: string}` not is part of `{p1: string, p2?: string}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `{p1: string, p2?: string}` means that if a value of this type has a `p2` property, it must be a `string`. Flow's width subtyping means that the `b` function could return `{p1: 'foo', p2: 6}`. Basically, if you have something of type `{p1: string}` you know it has a `p1` property but you don't know anything about its other properties.

Because of this, if Flow allowed you to take something of type `{p1: string}` and pass it to the `a` function which expects the type `{p1: string, p2?: string}`, the `a` function could check if the `p2` property exists, and if so it could assume that it is a `string`. However, it could actually be a `number` as detailed above. This will break type safety.